General formula for calculating $\prod_i^n (1+a_i)$
Does anyone know the general formula for calculating $\prod_i^n (1+a_i)$, where $a_i \ge 0$?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_roots_of_a_polynomial

$$\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(1+a_i\right) \,\, = \,\, \displaystyle\sum_{S \,\subseteq \, \{1,\, 2,\, 3,\, \dots\,,\, n\}} \,\,\,\left(\,\prod_{i \, \in \, S} \, a_i\right)$$
There will be exactly $2^n$ terms in the sum, one for each subset of $\{1,\, 2,\, 3,\, \dots,\, n\}$. Each term will have coefficient $1$. The term that is equal to $1$ corresponds to the case in which $S$ is the empty subset, and the product is the empty product.

In the special case of distinct prime numbers $p_i$, your product corresponds exactly to the sum of the divisors of $\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$, so we have:
$$\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(1+p_i\right) \,\, = \,\, \sigma_1\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\right)$$
Where $\sigma_1$ is the sum of divisors function and $p_i$ are distinct prime numbers.

For example, if $\,p_1 = 2,\, p_2 = 3,\, p_3 = 5,\,$ then we have
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=1}^{3} \left(1+p_i\right) \,\, &= \,\, 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \, =\, 72 \\\\
&=\,\sigma_1\left(\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=1}^{3} p_i\right) \, = \, \sigma_1\left(2\cdot 3 \cdot 5\right) \,=\, \sigma_1(30)\\\\
&=\,1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 10 + 15 + 30 \,=\, 72
\end{align}

Thank you very much for your answer. It's very clear

I understand now. Thank you for patiently explaining
